# Windows Service (.NET) Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows-services

When starting the windows service, an error occurs:

> The service could not be started. System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
> Could not load file or assembly "Quartz, Version = 3.1.0.0, Culture =
> neutral, PublicKeyToken = f6b8c98a402cc8a4" or one of their
> dependencies. The specified file cannot be found. Filename: 'Quartz,
> Version = 3.1.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken =
> f6b8c98a402cc8a4'    at Vlantify.WinServ.VlantifyService.OnStart
> (String [] args)    at
> System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback (Object
> state)

Errors also appear if you remove this nuget package, only then already with other packages, for example serilog.

This error began to appear when the Presenatation layer of the application was redone from MVC to Windows service, I note that MVC works fine with these packages.

The files of the required libraries are located in the bin folder, I do not understand why the error occurs and writes that the specified file was not found, I have already tried reinstalling nuget packages.

If anyone knows what could be the matter, please help.

Comment: Have you tried Publishing this project?

Comment: Did you fix it?

Comment: no, but I'm using the release version

Comment: no, not fixed yet

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that it has to do with the location of **packages** folder relative to your old/new project. All packages go into **packages** folder.
I've had some kind of similar problem few weeks ago when I uninstalled/reinstalled the packages but still kept giving me errors.
You can follow these steps to check:

- Unload your project
- Right-click -> Edit .csproj
  You will see references to packages, something like:

`<Reference Include="Autofac, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da, processorArchitecture=MSIL"<HintPath>..\packages\Autofac.5.0.0\lib\net461\Autofac.dll</HintPath> </Reference>`

- Check whether the path in `<HintPath>` relatively to the `.csproj` file of current project is correct. If not, fix the path (for all the packages, in cause the error shows for other packages too), or change the location of **packages** folder (carefull cause it might break references of other projects, if solution has many projects).

Not sure if it will help you or not, but it helped me.

Comment: did not help :(

Comment: So the upper steps everything is ok. Hm. Did you try removing the package from references, then re-adding by right-clicking on references and browsing inside packages->package_you_want->... .dll ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by itself, I don't even know what I did :) Thanks to all

Comment: It fixed itself because you restarted the windows service.  This is required after any type of dll modification. ;)